# symfony 1.4.18 installation failed

Tags: symfony1

sorry about my question before

i installed the symfony 1.4.18 from installation manual and finish
but there's problem
css not found
in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/mine/web/sf/sf_default/css/screen.css" />
```

when i search that file screen.css is under directory

```
lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf/sf_default
```

so when i look from the index.php file, there is code like this:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

what i suppose to do to fixed that?

Comment: my php version not compatible with symfony 2 coz my php version is 5.1, and almost web server version like that :)

Comment: Symfony1.4 needs at least php 5.2.4, so if you have to upgrade anyway, upgrade to php5.4 and use Symfony2.1

Answer (score 0):

You should add /sf alias to your virtual host config. Take a look at example.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com 
    DocumentRoot "C:\path\web"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
 <Directory "C:\path\web">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All  
     Allow from All
 </Directory>

 Alias /sf "C:\path\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf"
  <Directory "C:\pathlib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: how to upload to hosting like hostgator or godaddy? there's other way install the symfony skip that step?

Comment: I don't think it's possible on shared hosting. However you can move symfony css/image files to your public directory, and manually change css/image links used in your project to the new path.

Comment: how can i to do that? where's the code to change that? i'm sorry because i just start the symfony framework